# how to set default ip as 0.0.0.0 for a django project to debug in visual studio 2015?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2015, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I am developing a `django rest framework` application using visual studio 2015, python 2.7, django 1.9. I have enabled CORS. I can access it from other origin when I run it through command prompt as `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8086`. But, in visual studio auto debug, it runs on 127.0.0.0. I want to configure visual studio to run the server on specified ip (ie. 0.0.0.0). So, that debugging will be easy.
I have tried with setting default port and address from `site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py`.
and also able to set default port in visual studio property of the project. But, unable to set the default ip.

Can any one help me to configure the ip 0.0.0.0 as default not the default one (127.0.0.1) in visual studio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somehow I am able to solve the problem by modifying the `Arguments` in the `Run Server Command` in the property window to `runserver 0.0.0.0:%SERVER_PORT% $(CommandLineArguments)`. But, I guess this is not the proper solution. Because, remodifying it back generates exception.

Comment: Your solution sounds fine to me. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Yes Aya, for the timing its fine. But, I want to know if there is any way to configure somewhere in visual studio configurations. So that, later on if I need to remodify the settings it should not create any problem. Because it does not accepts the previous configuration once modified.

Comment: did my solution work for you?

Comment: Yes e4c5, your solution gave me so many ideas but my requirement was different. I found one solution and posted as one answer. Again Thank you for your lovely explanation.

Answer (score 6):

After so many struggle I found one solution, want to share it with you. Hope you will like it.
open `<your python location>\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py` and find one code where it deal with `self.addr`.
`if not self.addr:
    self.addr = '::1' if self.use_ipv6 else '127.0.0.1'`
It sets default address to 127.0.0.1 change it to `'0.0.0.0'`. Now, if you run your server with only command `./manage.py runserver` It will run on 0.0.0.0, even from visual studio.

Good luck.

Comment: God bless you!!

Answer (score 2):

First of all `0.0.0.0` is not an IP. It stands for "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine". When you start the development server as

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8086
```

It will serve on `127.0.0.1` and whatever other IP address you have configured for your network interface(s)

Similarly it cannot server on `127.0.0.0` because that's a broadcast address.

If you have any other IP configured on your computer (eg `192.168.1.1`) you can type that into your browser on any computer in your lan or into visual studio where an IP address is asked for.

Comment: Thank you e4c5. But the problem is when I am running `runserver 9192` and try to access with my ip it shows `There was an error connecting to http://192.168.1.63:9192/`. There may be another problem but I am unable to figure it out. could you please give some idea what problems it could be?

Comment: Sorry, typo in my answer. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way that can be added/changed in `"args"`'s value list.

```
$ cat .vscode/launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This works! In the args you have to add the ip and the port, so example if you want to run it on 8400 port: ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8400"].